# How to get the number of values from a database field for the last 10 days

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a database which has fields like id, name, unit, date & time.

For ex: id:01 name:water unit:kel date&time: 2020-03-21 13:26:25.885758

Like this I have around 50 elements of data in my database with different date&time.

I tried generating the last 10 days from today, but I don't know how to do it for the date&time of the database.

I need the count of last 10 days of date&time.

For example if I have 50 records and 12 records are available from today to last 10days, I need the result of 12.

How to do this in pymongo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior answer `start` and `end` are reversed but concept is correct.  OP also wanted the count.  So we will shoe that and the individuals items, and let's assume no natural ordering so we'll enhance the answer to use `sort()` and `limit()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pymongo

client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://yourConnectionString")
coll   = client.yourDB.yourCollection

end = datetime.now()
start = end - timedelta(days=10)

start = end - timedelta(days=10)

#  This is the count:                                                                                               
count = coll.find({'dt': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}}).count()
print "count",count

#  To show the material, sorted recent-first and with a limit just for fun:                                         
for doc in coll.find({'dt': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}}).sort('dt',-1).limit(6):
    print doc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get today's datetime using datetime library, then use that as input for your query

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

start = datetime.now()
end = start - timedelta(days=10)

for doc in db.your_collection.find({'date_time': {'$gte': start, '$lt': end}}):
    print doc
```